# Gson parsing error Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

Tags: java, android, gson

I met a problem, but I don't know how to solve.Please help me, thank you!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu0me.png
when:

```
new Gson().fromJson(server_response,Model.class);
```

Gson  Error：

```
    Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2621
```

Comment: Is my answer useful to you?

Comment: @ShoebSiddique hi.I was in for this problem. 
{ "picurl": ["http:\/\/192.168.1.238:81\/upload\/postimg\/150510\/bc\/88177a488b_0.jpg", "http:\/\/192.168.1.238:81\/upload\/postimg\/150510\/bc\/88177a488b_1.jpg", "http:\/\/192.168.1.238:81\/upload\/postimg\/150510\/bc\/88177a488b_2.jpg", "http:\/\/192.168.1.238:81\/upload\/postimg\/150510\/bc\/88177a488b_3.jpg", "http:\/\/192.168.1.238:81\/upload\/postimg\/150510\/bc\/88177a488b_4.jpg"] }  ----Escape character??

Answer (score 1):

You can do something very simply like this.

```
try {
                    ArrayList<String> _pics = new ArrayList<String>();
                    JSONObject _jObject = new JSONObject("YOUR_JSON_STRING");
                    JSONArray _picArr  = _jObject.getJSONArray("picurl");
                    for (int i = 0; i < _picArr.length(); i++) {

                        String _picPath  = _picArr.getString(i);
                        _pics.add(_picPath);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Convert your response into `JSONObject`

**Step 2:** Pass `picurl` JSONArray to `Gson`.

```
Type type = type = new TypeToken<List<Model>>() {}.getType();
Gson objGson = new Gson();
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseString);
List<Model> result = objGson.fromJson(response .getJSONArray("picurl").toString(), type);
```

Comment: .I judge because escape character ,what should I do?

Comment: {
"picurl":
 ["http:\/\/192.168.1.238:81\/upload\/postimg\/150510\/bc\/88177a488b_0.jpg",
 "http:\/\/192.168.1.238:81\/upload\/postimg\/150510\/bc\/88177a488b_1.jpg",
 "http:\/\/192.168.1.238:81\/upload\/postimg\/150510\/bc\/88177a488b_2.jpg",
 "http:\/\/192.168.1.238:81\/upload\/postimg\/150510\/bc\/88177a488b_3.jpg",
 "http:\/\/192.168.1.238:81\/upload\/postimg\/150510\/bc\/88177a488b_4.jpg"]
}    @Vicky Thakor